# Printing pictures in Access Forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using vba to display pictures from file instead of a dummy image inserted into my form detail (i.e setting the Picture property of the Access image control), using:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
On Error Resume Next
Me![imgFromFile].Picture = Me![txtPath]
End Sub
```

This works well when displaying individual forms on screen, updating the image to the appropriate picture from the file location defined in "txtpath".

However, when I try to print all the forms (continuous) I only get the same picture that was last shown in the individual form display.

Is there any way to update the image field for each object prior to print?

Comment: On Error Resume Next is something that should be used only very rarely. It discards all errors, and you have no idea whether you're ignoring the right one or ignoring something important.

Answer (score 1):

Forms are for displaying and editing data, reports are for printing.

Comment: Thanks Remou
I realised that.  But my 'customer' wanted a print out of all the forms (for whatever reason!).
I have already produced a report which gives the same results.
But, thanks anyway for your input
Wilkie53

Comment: @Steve Wilkie get medieval on your customer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code. It will print the form as it appears on the screen.

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, "MyFormName", True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
```